# Mechanize com Nokogiri: tentando buscar informações em divs

Tags: regex, ruby, web-crawler

Olá!

Estou montando um crawler para obter informações de produtos, para isso estou usando o mechanize e por consequência o nokogiri,
Tenho uma URL (http://www.megamamute.com.br/brother%205652) que retorna somente um produto, porem não consigo acertar a expressão regular para pegar o preço desse item, fragmento  HTML exemplo:

HTML

```
                <div class="pager top" id="PagerTop_66064345"></div><div id="ResultItems_66064345" class="prateleira vitrine"><div class="prateleira vitrine n1colunas"><ul><li layout="45e718bf-51b0-49c4-8882-725649af0594" class="informatica--teclado-notebook-tablet-pen-drive-|-megamamute last">

    <input type="hidden" class="x-id" value="55492" />

    <div class="x-product">

        <div class="x-selos">
            <p class="flag desconto-10--off-no-boleto">Desconto 10% off no boleto</p>

            <p class="flag Informática" style="display:none;">Informática</p>
        </div>

        <div class="x-get-skuId x-hide"><div class="buy-button-normal" id="55492" name="55492"><a class="buy-button-normal-a55492" href="https://www.megamamute.com.br/checkout/cart/add?sku=55492&qty=1&seller=1&sc=1&price=224900&cv=254ca7d1b9d7fb34e47ca55ceec1b2c0_geral:0F62E16B17B76A6FE17EC7C23A655D8B&sc=1" title="Comprar">Comprar</a><input type="hidden" value="cart" class="buy-button-normal-go-to-cart-55492" /></div></div>

        <div class="x-departamento">
            Multifuncional Laser Monocromática
        </div>

        <div class="x-image">
            <a class="x-productImage" title="Impressora Multifuncional Brother DCP-L5652DN Laser Mono" href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p">
                <img src="http://megamamute.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/6658677-500-500/55492_original.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="55492_original" id="" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <h2 class="product-name">
            <a title="Impressora Multifuncional Brother DCP-L5652DN Laser Mono" href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p">
                Impressora Multifuncional Brother DCP-L5652DN Laser Mono
            </a>
        </h2>

        <div data-trustvox-product-code="55492"></div>

                    <div class="x-price">
                <a title="Impressora Multifuncional Brother DCP-L5652DN Laser Mono" href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p">

                                            <span class="oldPrice">
                             R$ 2.899,00
                        </span> 

                        <span class="x-bestPrice">
                            R$ 2.249,00 
                        </span>

                    <span class="x-installment">
                                                     10X de <strong>R$ 224,90</strong> sem juros
                                            </em> 
                </a>

            </div>

            <!--<div class="x-opiniao">-->
            <!--    <span class="rating-produto avaliacao0">0</span> <span class="navaliacao">(0)</span>-->
            <!--</div>-->



            <div class="x-info-product">
                <ul>
                    <li class="x-info"><a href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p"></a></li>
                    <li class="x-favorite"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="x-move"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="x-add"><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="x-hover">
                <div class="x-buy"> <a class="x-productImage" title="Impressora Multifuncional Brother DCP-L5652DN Laser Mono" href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p"> Comprar </a></div>
                <a class="x-hoverHref" title="Impressora Multifuncional Brother DCP-L5652DN Laser Mono" href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="x-info"><a href="http://www.megamamute.com.br/impressora-multifuncional-brother-dcp-l5652dn-laser-mono/p"></a></li>
                    <li class="x-favorite"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="x-move"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="x-add"><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>


        <div class="x-brand"><p class="texto brand brother">brother</p></div>

</div>
```

E também já gostaria de adiantar e verificar como faria para pegar vários produtos, teria varias divs "x-product", não consegui entender uma maneira de montar um array com todas e buscar as informações dentro de cada uma,

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você estiver usando o nokogiri para extrair as informações das tags HTML, não vejo porquê usar expressão regular.

Segue um exemplo usando HTTParty (basta adaptar para a sua situação):

```
require 'httparty'
require 'nokogiri'

link = "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python"
response = HTTParty.get(link)
content = Nokogiri::HTML(response)

# Captura os dados presentes em todas as tags <a> com a class "question-hyperlink"
result = content.css('a[class=question-hyperlink]')

# Laço para percorrer e imprimir um por um
result.each do |question|
  puts(question.text)
end
```

Saída

> Importar módulo em python
>
> erro do tipo ValueError nos exercicios do livro Learn Python the Hard Way
>
> Erro ao passar parametro para a funçao user.set_password
>
> Uso da função set e for na mesma estrutura
>
> Saber anos, meses, dias, horas, etc… Que passaram desde uma determinada data
>
> Achar elemento duplicado em tempo O(n) e espaço O(1) [pendente]
>
> Como coverter string para objeto timestamp?
>
> O Python diz que o nome da minha função não existe [pendente]
>
> Erro ao recuperar JSON e utilizar API em Python
>
> Python não retorna arquivos dentro de um diretório
>
> [...]

Isso também deve resolver o problema para pegar várias divs 'x-product'.

Manda o feedback se eu entendi bem o teu problema e se a solução te ajudou.

Fico no aguardo.

Comment: eu vou fazer o teste, infelizmente estou com minha agenda lotada, vou tentar hoje a noite,
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter te ajudado!